# Update failed in Symfony 3.1

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I am working with two entities named `Profile` and `Blog` in Symfony 3.1. Here this two entities constitute one to many relationship. A `Profile` may create more than one `Blog` , beside a `Blog` belongs to one `Profile` . So to access Profile info from a `Blog` i want to create a `foreign key` in the `blog table` . I have already done that inside my code but major problem is that when I write this command-- `$ php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` , It shows
"nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata". Anyone can help me please... Here I provide the two classes I done...

**`//Profile.php`**

> ```
> <?php
> class Profile {
> /**
>  * @var int
>  */
> private $id;
>
> /**
>  * @var string
>  *
>  */
> private $userName;
>
> /**
>  * @var string
>  *
>  */
> private $email;
>
> /**
>  * @ORM\Column(name="url", type="string")
>  */
> private $url;
>
> /**
>  * Get id
>  *
>  * @return int
>  */
> public function getId()
> {
>     return $this->id;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Set userName
>  *
>  * @param string $userName
>  *
>  * @return Profile
>  */
> public function setUserName($userName)
> {
>     $this->userName = $userName;
>
>     return $this;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Get userName
>  *
>  * @return string
>  */
> public function getUserName()
> {
>     return $this->userName;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Set email
>  *
>  * @param string $email
>  *
>  * @return Profile
>  */
> public function setEmail($email)
> {
>     $this->email = $email;
>
>     return $this;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Get email
>  *
>  * @return string
>  */
> public function getEmail()
> {
>     return $this->email;
> } }
> ```

**Blog.php**

> class Blog 
>     {
>       /**
>        * @var int
>        */
>       private $id;
>
> ```
> /**
>  * @var string
>  */
> private $blogTitle;
>
> /**
>  * @var string
>  */
> private $blogContent;
>
> /**
>  *
>  *      >@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Profile",inversedBy="blogs")
>  *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="profile_id", referencedColumnName="id")
>  *
>  */
> private $product_id;
>
>
> /**
>  * Get id
>  *
>  * @return int
>  */
> public function getId()
> {
>     return $this->id;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Set blogTitle
>  *
>  * @param string $blogTitle
>  *
>  * @return Blog
>  */
> public function setBlogTitle($blogTitle)
> {
>     $this->blogTitle = $blogTitle;
>
>     return $this;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Get blogTitle
>  *
>  * @return string
>  */
> public function getBlogTitle()
> {
>     return $this->blogTitle;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Set blogContent
>  *
>  * @param string $blogContent
>  *
>  * @return Blog
>  */
> public function setBlogContent($blogContent)
> {
>     $this->blogContent = $blogContent;
>
>     return $this;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Get blogContent
>  *
>  * @return string
>  */
> public function getBlogContent()
> {
>     return $this->blogContent;
> }
>
> /**
>  * @return Profile 
>  */
> public function getprofileId()
> {
>     return $this->profile_id;
> }
>
> /**
>  * @param Profile $profile_id
>  */
> public function setProfileId(Profile $profile _id)
> {
>     $this->profile_id = $profile_id;
> }
> ```
>
> }

Comment: I think, you forget about `@ORM\Entity()` annotation for your entities. Try [this link](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-entity). And here is gist with [entity example](https://gist.github.com/kaduev13/bd759be974ffec5cbd51713ca3de593a).

Comment: I have already tried but nothing else...

Answer (score 0):

Your entities' annotations are wrong. They should be something like:

```
//Profile.php
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity\Profile
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Profile {
 /**
  * @var int
  */
 private $id;

 /**
  * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Blog", mappedBy="product_id")
  */
 private $blogs;

 ...

}
```

And the other entity:

//Blog.php

```
class Blog { 
 /** * @var int */ 
 private $id;
 ...
 /**
  * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Profile",inversedBy="blogs")
  *  @ORM\JoinColumn(name="profile_id", referencedColumnName="id")
  */
 private $product_id;

 ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Oscar Pérez. I have already done that but failed. The problem is that Symfony 3.1 doesn't support this format. This version support the migrations formula. Already I have succeed by generating new migration class. And I have used up() method to do the task.

Comment: Please, add an answer to your question with the correct solution, so we all can have it as future reference.

Comment: i answered this question about 8 minutes ago

Comment: Perfect! Thanky-ou very much

Answer (score 0):

At First I run this command in the terminal..

```
$ php bin/console doctrine:migrations:generate
```

Then I write my code inside the `up()` method. Below is my code..

```
class Version20160831074611 extends AbstractMigration
{
    /**
     * @param Schema $schema
     */
    public function up(Schema $schema)
    {

        $blogTable = $schema->getTable('blog');
        $product1Table =$schema->getTable('product1');

        if(!$blogTable->hasColumn('product1_id'))
       {
            $blogTable->addColumn('product1_id','integer')->setNotnull(false);
        }
        if(!$blogTable->hasIndex('FK_product_idx'))
       {
            $blogTable->addIndex(['product1_id'],'FK_product_idx');
        }
        if(!$blogTable->hasForeignKey('FK_product1'))
        {
            $blogTable->addForeignKeyConstraint($product1Table,
                ['product1_id'],
                ['id'],
                ['OnUpdate'=>'CASCADE','OnDelete'=>'CASCADE','FK_product1']
            );
        }

    }

    /**
     * @param Schema $schema
     */
    public function down(Schema $schema)
    {
        // this down() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your          needs

    }
}
```

Finally I run this command in the terminal and done...

```
$ php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate 20160831074611
```